# React - Iterate through nested array and check values of indexes in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multidimensional-array, nested, iteration

I'm learning React and working on a Conway's Game of Life project. The project is mostly done but I am having trouble implementing game logic. I have a 2D array that represents the game board. Each index in the 2D array represents a square in the board. I have it set up so that functional components handle the displaying of the board and which squares are "alive" in the Game of Life sense. In my App.js I have a `componentDidMount` function that creates a new board filled with random "alive" squares that also calls a `timer` function that creates a new board every couple of seconds.

I am attempting to use `componentDidUpdate` to check the board each time the board changes and apply the Game of Life rules:

*Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbors dies, as if by under population.*

*Any live cell with two or three live neighbors lives on to the next generation.*

*Any live cell with more than three live neighbors dies, as if by overpopulation.*

*Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbors becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.*

My logic is when `componentDidUpdate` runs I will loop through the 2D array (the game board) and check the neighboring squares to see if they are populated. Then, apply the game rules, and determine if that particular square lives or dies or reproduces. Then after each square is checked and it is determined whether it should live or die I will update state with the values of the new game board. Then `timer` runs again, creates the next round, and `componentDidUpdate` will evaluate the next changes to the board once again.

This is not working. Here is the code for `componentDidUpdate`. What's wrong with my approach? :

```
// Should apply Game of Life rules and decide with squares are alive/dead every time the board is updated
  componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
    //console.log('PrevState is : ' + prevProps, prevState);
    const oldBoard = this.state.board;
    const newBoard = this.state.nextBoard;

    console.log('oldBoard ' + oldBoard);

/*    // Checks that board has changed and prevents infinite loop in componentDidUpdate
      for(let x = 0; x < this.state.boardHeight; x++) {
        for(let y = 0; y < this.state.boardWidth; y++) {
          let neighborCount = 0;
          // Game of Life logic pertaining to squares being alive/dead
          neighborCount += oldBoard[x - 1][y - 1];
          neighborCount += oldBoard[x][y - 1];
          neighborCount += oldBoard[x + 1][y - 1];
          neighborCount += oldBoard[x - 1][y];
          neighborCount += oldBoard[x + 1][y];
          neighborCount += oldBoard[x - 1][y + 1];
          neighborCount += oldBoard[x][y + 1];
          neighborCount += oldBoard[x + 1][y + 1];

          // If square has 2 live neighbors it stays alive
          if(neighborCount == 2) {
            newBoard[x][y] = oldBoard[x][y];
          }
          // If square has exactly 3 neighbors a new life square is born
          else if (neighborCount == 3) {
            newBoard[x][y] = 1;
          }
          // Is square has more than 3 live neighbors it dies
          else if(neighborCount > 3){
            newBoard[x][y] = 0;
          }
        }
      }

      if(newBoard !== oldBoard) {
        // after applying rules set the nextBoard
        this.setState({ board: newBoard });
      }
    */

  }
```

It would probably be easier to view the whole App.js on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Nicknyr/FCC_Game_Of_Life). I think my logic is correct but maybe how I am looping through and evaluating the values of the arrays is incorrect, or maybe my use of `componentDidUpdate` is incorrect.

Comment: do your `console.log`'s look correct?

Comment: console.logging the oldBoard value appears correct. Every 2 seconds it updates and shows an array of random 1's and 0's.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're comparing against `newBoard`, which is something you never set.  I believe you can remove `newBoard` from state completely and start checking

```
const oldBoard = prevState.board;
const newBoard = this.state.board;
```

in your `componentDidUpdate` function.